# How to apply formatting to text boxes specified in code

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for a good way to put the results of a query into a text box.
I'm putting a value in the text box I got with Controls.Find, but the format doesn't seem to apply to the .text property. (I checked that it applies to the .value property. )
Is there any good way to do this?

```
Dim i As Integer = 1
Dim ctrl As Control()
Dim txtBox As String = "textbox" + CStr(i)

ctrl = Me.Controls.Find(txtBox , True)
CType(ctrl(0), TextBox).Text = "0.950"
```

Comment: You appear to be using Windows Forms. Is that correct? if so then there is no `Value` property. It's pointless casting your `Control` reference as type `TextBox` because `Text` is a property of the `Control` class.

Comment: You aren't doing any formatting in that code. You're simply assigning a `String` to the `Text` of a `TextBox`, which will display that `String`, i.e. you'll see "0.950" in the `TextBox`. If you expect to display the result of a query then you might actually have to use that result, rather than a literal `String`. Assuming that that result is a numeric type, you can call its `ToString` method and specify the format. There's lots of information around about formatting numbers, if that's actually what you are trying to do.